# CCLabelTTF contentSize different in iOS 6 and iOS 7 - cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I'm using `Cocos2dx` in my project. And I've noticed that `CCLabelTTF` draws text in 2-3 pixels higher than in `iOS 7`. Line space in `iOS 6` is also bigger than in `iOS 7`.
I was tested that on 2 different devices. Code is simple:

```
CCLabelTTF *fLabel = CCLabelTTF::create(title, "Helvetica Bold", 14);
fLabel->setPosition(centerPoint);
node->addChild(fLabel);
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: try to write x/int value instead of 14 in CCLabelTTF::create(title, "Helvetica Bold",x/5);  where x= screenSize.width;

Comment: Nope, This won't help. I found the reason

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. I found solution of that. I'm using cocos2dx 2.2 now and there is bug in `CCImage.mm`.
Cocos2dx using deprecated method to get string size. That's why string size in iOS 6 is different than in iOS 7.
I've edited `_calculateStringSize` method in `CCImage.mm` file, here is my code:

```
static CGSize _calculateStringSize(NSString *str, id font, CGSize *constrainSize)
{
    NSArray *listItems = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];
    CGSize dim = CGSizeZero;
    CGSize textRect = CGSizeZero;
    textRect.width = constrainSize->width > 0 ? constrainSize->width
                                          : 0x7fffffff;
    textRect.height = constrainSize->height > 0 ? constrainSize->height
                                          : 0x7fffffff;

      CGSize tmp;
    if([str respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)]){
        NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                NSFontAttributeName: font
        };
        tmp = [str boundingRectWithSize:textRect options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributes context:nil].size;
        [paragraphStyle release];
    }else{
        tmp = [str sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:textRect];
    }

    if (tmp.width > dim.width)
    {
       dim.width = tmp.width; 
    }

    dim.height += tmp.height;


   return dim;
}
```

And I suggest you to use this method to calculate string size in your projects.
Hope it will helps for someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
multiply the scale value to font size.

try this 

CCEGLView* pEGLView = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();
float frameSize = pEGLView->getFrameSize();
float scaleFactor = frameSize.width / designResolutionSize.width ;
CCLabelTTF *fLabel = CCLabelTTF::create(title, "Helvetica Bold", 14*scaleFactor);
```

Answer (score 0):

There were minor issues with Timur Mustafaev's implementation. This one should work correctly:

```
static CGSize _calculateStringSize(NSString *str, id font, CGSize *constrainSize)
{
    NSArray *listItems = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];
    CGSize dim = CGSizeZero;
    CGSize textRect = CGSizeZero;
    textRect.width = constrainSize->width > 0 ? constrainSize->width
                                              : 0x7fffffff;
    textRect.height = constrainSize->height > 0 ? constrainSize->height
                                              : 0x7fffffff;


    for (NSString *s in listItems)
    {
        CGSize tmp;

        // Method only exists on iOS6+.
        if([s respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)]){
            NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
            tmp = [s boundingRectWithSize:textRect options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributes context:nil].size;
        } else {
            tmp = [s sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:textRect];
        }

        if (tmp.width > dim.width)
        {
           dim.width = tmp.width; 
        }

        dim.height += tmp.height;
    }

    dim.width = ceilf(dim.width);
    dim.height = ceilf(dim.height);

    return dim;
}
```